# How to hide extension and containing folder with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new to the .htaccess file and I've been trying to hide the extension .php and the public folder from the URL

In other words, I want this:

```
site.com/public/index.php
```

to look like this:

```
site.com/index
```

I was able to do this 2 things separately, but I couldn't make them at the same time...

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide information on how you've managed to do these things separately, and we may be able to advise on how to combine them.

Comment: RewruteRule (.*)/? index.php?url=$1. Then you receive the query string in $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and handle 'index' as you wish to handle it. Just try it. After applying this to your .htaccess, echo the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. The posibilities are yours to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need 2 rules.

Firstly, when you receive a request for `site.com/public/index.php` , you have to tell the client to send another request for `site.com/index` by doing this:

`RewriteRule ^site\.com/public/index\.php/?$ site.com/index [R=301,L]`

The R=301 flag says that you are sending an HTTP 301 'moved permanently' header. When the client receives this, they will send a new request but for `site.com/index`.

Next, you need a rule to deal with requests for `site.com/index` like this:

`RewriteRule ^site\.com/index$ index.php [L]`

So your resulting .htaccess file should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site\.com/public/index\.php/?$ site.com/index [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^site\.com/index$ index.php [L]
```